# set permissions for menu items (Ax Dynamics 2009)

Tags: axapta, user-permissions, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm having some problems with granting access to a certain menu item in Ax Dynamics 2009. The situation is this: We have a form with transactions of items (based on InventTrans). This form displays all transactions for a particular item, like sales, purchases, transfers,... You can right click on the number of any of these transactions and choose "Go to main table". This takes you to the form with the details on this particular transaction.

But when some of our users do this, they get the error "You don't have enough privileges to execute Menu Item Sales Order". However, they are able to go to this form through the main menu.

So I'm assuming it's this particular method to which these users don't have access. I know where I can set user group permissions, I just can't seem to find the right place of this menu item..

Does anyone know where I can find this menu item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'Go to main table form' actions are based on other display-type Menu Items (normally found under the Misc folder), not necessarily the primary menu item.

My first step would be to look at the properties of the table in question, and see what the 'FormRef' property is, and see if granting access to that menu item fixes it.

If it doesn't have a menu item or it doesn't work, then I would suggest trying a 'brute force' type approach - it takes a while, but grant another user you have access to full access and trim down the access levels until you find the specific menu item. You can start with the module-level keys and work your way down, not unlike a binary tree search.

Comment: On what table should I look for the FormRef property? The one where I try to use "Go To Main Table" or the one where I want to be send to? The first one it references itself, the second one isn't filled in.

Comment: It would be the table you would be sent to. As I said, if the property isn't filled in, you may want to try to 'brute force' the security. You could also try the [Security Profile Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/05/25/ax-2009-securityprofiler-tool.aspx) (in a test environment), but I haven't had much luck using it.